# Java Result Set Query Issue With Boolean Field

Tags: java, combobox, boolean, resultset

I have a database with two fields `ItemName` and `Available`. I am attempting to fetch the available column for a user specified item name entered into a  `combobox`. Once fetched `if` `available` has a value of `true` then show message saying it is available or ideally have it update a label when an item from the `combobox` drop down is selected, showing in real-time whether or not an item is available. This is my attempt so far but depending on what I change it either does nothing or gives an error of argument mismatching.

**Edit: Solved**

```
private void handleCheckToggle(ActionEvent event) {
        String item = comboBoxItem.getValue();
        String checkAvailable = "SELECT AVAILABLE FROM ES.EQUIPMENT WHERE ITEMNAME = ?";

        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(checkAvailable);
            pst.setString(1, item);
            pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                if(rs.getBoolean("available")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item + " is available.");
                }
                else ;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
```

Comment: ResultSet may be case sensitive (I am not sure). If the field is "Available" then you should use `rs.getBoolean("Available")` (or simply `rs.getBoolean(1)`).

Comment: Have tried both and neither has worked. Wondering if there is something else wrong. Does it look like it should work?

Comment: Show the error message then.

Comment: Error message came up before when using a label and I believe it was the label actually causing the issue. Now when I click the button the call the actionevent simply nothing happens. It gets all the way up to the if statement and then doesn't attempt the if. But print on both the true if and the else and nothing showed.

Comment: I'd say don't swallow the exception. Print the stack trace inside the handler, you might get some clues.

Comment: Ok got 'Invalid operation at current cursor postion'

Comment: Where is `rs` created and assigned?

Comment: Yup ok. Stupid mistake feel like an idiot now. Thanks though!

Comment: Although now it has been defined still getting the same error. Wondering if the result set is turning up empty

Comment: @Dabiuteef `getXXX` methods on a result set must be case-insensitive as documented in the API.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok thanks.

Comment: So doesn't seem to be returning anything at the moment. I is also returning thee incorrect true or false value of what is specified in available, returning true all the time. No errors anymore though.

Comment: Ok got it to work with a bit of tinkering. Thanks for your help!